# Content of iframe isn't seen in screenshot

Tags: javascript, iframe, casperjs

I try to do screenshot the page, but iframe doesn't be visible on image. 
But I can to fill fields in iframe. 
[It's my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuIMW.png), but [it's CasperJS's screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N0bj.png).

```js
casper.waitForSelector('div#iframeBlock', function success(){
  this.page.switchToChildFrame('iframe');
  this.click(".button");
 }); 
casper.wait(30000);

casper.waitForSelector('.form.js-validate', function success(){

   this.capture('_1.png');

  });
```

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug in PhantomJS. Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: PhantomJS version 2.1.1
CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta5

Comment: @ArtjomB. I add the events: resource.error, page.error, remote.message and casper.page.onResourceTimeout. Only error: ResourceError:
    "errorCode": 203,
    "errorString": "Error downloading server replied: Not Found",
 But this error has appeared after some actions in iframe.

Comment: No idea. Maybe you need to access the page through a proxy (judging by the HTTP status code 203).